# cannot convert ‘char*’ to ‘int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int median(int*, int)’ array2 = median(array,size);

Tags: c++, pointers, char, int, median

My problem is as I specify in the title: test_median.cpp:

> In function ‘int main()’: test_median.cpp:26:27: error: cannot convert
>   ‘char*’ to ‘int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int median(int*, int)’

```
array2 = median(array,size);
```

So here is my code. This is the tester code;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "IpFunctions.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int size;
cout<< "size gir" <<endl;
cin >> size;

int i;
char array[size];

cout<< "değerleri gir"<<endl;

for (i=0;i<size;i=i+1)
{
cin >> array[i];
}

char array2[size];

array2 = median(array,size);

cout<<"array2 = "<<array2<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

This is the median function code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int median(char array[], int size)
{
int i = 0;
int m,n;
while (i<size)
{
    if (array[i]>array[i+1])
    {
    m = array[i]; n = array[i+1];
    array[i] = n; array[i+1] = m;
    i=i+1;
    }
    else
    {
    i=i+1;
    }
}

return *array;

}
```

And finally "IpFunctions.h" header:

```
// this is just a headerfile that you add your Image processing functions' prototypes.
// when testing your functions with a main function
// main needs a prototype of the function

//Image medianfiltering(Image &inimg, const int size );
int median(int array[],int size);

// when you type a function add the header here !!! 
// such as 
// Image negative(Image &inimg);
```

So I just wanted to make a function to take the median of an array and return that array.

Comment: Signature of function `median` definition isn't same as it's declaration. Notice the function arguments types being different.

Comment: oh ok so i changed all char's to int now i get this error   test_median.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test_median.cpp:26:8: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘int’ to ‘int [(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)size) + -1)) + 1)]’
 array2 = median(array,size);

Comment: Please try to understand the error message. It gives you hint about the return type of `median` being assigned to. `array2` is a character array but `median` returns `int`.

Comment: oh i see after using the function to an integer and printing it i see only one integer instead of a string. now i need to figure out how to get string as retrun. thank you for your answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the header

```
int median(int array[],int size);
```

in the .cpp file

```
int median(char array[], int size)
```

your main is trying to invoke the first one (its the only one it knows about)

Comment: i changed all char's to int now i get this error test_median.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: test_median.cpp:26:8: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘int’ to ‘int [(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)size) + -1)) + 1)]’ array2 = median(array,size);

Comment: That is a new question.

Comment: @korel - read the error message and read the code, look at the return type definition of median